# Node.js - WebSocket only works when refreshing the page

Tags: javascript, node.js, websocket, socket.io, connection

I am trying to communicate with the websocket in Node.js. It works when the page is first opened but I cannot receive messages without refreshing the page later.

**HTML PAGES WEBSOCKET CODE:**

```
var ws ;

function init() {
   ws = new WebSocket('ws://localhost:40510');

    ws.onopen = function () {
       ws.send('test')
    }

     ws.onmessage = function (ev) {
      console.log(ev)
    }
 }

  window.addEventListener("load", init, false);
```

**SERVER SIDE CODE:**

```
app.get('/sayfayiYenile', function (req, res) {
 wss.on('connection', function connection(ws) {
    ws.send('abc');
  });
  res.end('test')
});
```

**CHROME CONSOLE:**

```
MessageEvent {isTrusted: true, data: "abc", origin: "ws://localhost:40510", lastEventId: "", source: null, …}
```

When I press the button, it goes into the '/sayfayiYenile' post method on the server side but does not send the message. Then I refresh the HTML page and send the message.

Answer (score 0):

Your `.get` method isn't emitting a message, it's wrapping the `.on("connection")` websocket logic instead. You should place the `ws.on` functionality outside the `.get` and implement logic to send a message to a specific connection.

Example:

```js
const connections = [];

wss.on('connection', function connection(ws) {
  ws.send("Welcome...");

  // Store the list of connections for later use
  connections.push(ws);
});

app.get('/sayfayiYenile', function (req, res) {
  // Iterate over the current connected clients and send a message
  // @todo implement logic here to filter out specific connections
  connections.forEach(function(connection) {
    connection.send('abc');
  });
});
```